# Rundeck : List all the jobs for specific project

Tags: rest, api, rundeck

I have API call which was giving all the jobs within one project.

```
https://localhost:3423/api/25/project/project_name/jobs/export?authtoken=asndkajsnfkjareeknfkjsafaksd
```

But how could anyone tell me how I can select a few specific jobs with the same project, I read the official doc but it is not that much clear.

**from the official document:** [link](https://rundeck.org/docs/api/#listing-jobs)

> The following parameters can also be used to narrow down the result set.
>
> **idlist**: specify a comma-separated list of Job IDs to include

I tried with following GET but nothings workout:

```
https://localhost:3423/api/25/project/project_name/job/34d9ac3b-e6d0-4e43-ad68-0b0faa71ebf8/export?authtoken=asndkajsnfkjareeknfkjsafaksd

https://localhost:3423/api/25/project/project_name/job/['34d9ac3b-e6d0-4e43-ad68-0b0faa71ebf8','b284aba1-81b2-4b0f-ba33-dd6e37589fbf']/export?authtoken=asndkajsnfkjareeknfkjsafaksd
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `idlist` is a parameter to put at the end of the URL, in your case:

```
https://localhost:3423/api/25/project/project_name/jobs/export?authtoken=asndkajsnfkjareeknfkjsafaksd&idlist=aaaa-cc-ddd,xxxx-yy-zzzz
```

Answer (score 0):

That's works for me:

```
curl -G -s -H "Accept: application/xml" -H "X-RunDeck-Auth-Token:YOURIDTOKEN" http://YOURHOSTNAME:4440/api/14/jobs?idlist=ID1,ID2,ID3 -d project=YOURPROJECT | grep "<name>"
```

Comment: This is using an url version described as deprecated by the documentation (`/api/14/jobs/export?project=prj_name`).